# Does gnome-schedule run things on startup if the run time is missed?

Tags: cron, scheduled

I have a script that I would like to run daily. I set it up in gnome-schedule to run every day at 00:00, and I'm wondering whether it will run on startup if my computer was not turned on at 00:00. If not, is there a way to make it do that?

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/52335/job-scheduling-using-crontab-what-will-happen-when-computer-is-shutdown-during-t

Comment: It looks like the answer is 'no'. It didn't run this morning when I started up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome-schedule is just a GUI to cron. Cron itself doesn't support what you're asking for but anacron does. Examples of its usage are in the link provided in Ward's comment.

Answer (score 0):

was looking into startup launch myself and got to here with cron: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

it says you can launch from start by setting time to @reboot before your command.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

gnome-schedule depend on/use anacron, so I think it would not miss your job.

Comment: It uses cron, not anacron.